# python仮想環境の切り替え

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

Pythonの初心者で、現在は主に言語について学習中です。

Pythonの環境を構築するのに「anaconda4.1.1(Python 3.5.2)」を使用しました。
Python3.6が出ているとのことで、この際環境について勉強しようと思っているのですが、理解ができません。

まず、次のように、Python3.6の環境を構築しました。

```
c:\conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
-
# conda environments:
#
py36                     C:\Users\(uname)\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py36
root                  *  C:\Users\(uname)\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
```

質問です。

1.「activate py36」で、仮想環境を切り替えられるらしいのですが、できません。
　　切り替え方法を教えてください。
　　※メインシェルは「powershell」を使用しています。
　　※シェルをコマンドプロンプトを使用した時には、切り替えられました。

2.コマンドプロンプトで切り替えることができましたが、
「(py36)c:>」とプロンプトが変わりました。(py36)が表示されている間は、python3.6の
　仮想環境になることは推測できますが、デフォルトをPython3.6にすることは可能でしょうか？
　例えばrootのバージョンを3.6にアップデートにしてから、
　3.5.2を新しく構築するものなのでしょうか？

3.仮想環境を切り替えるでネットで調べていたのですが、「virtualenv」というものも
　あるらしいのですが、activeateコマンドとどう違うのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Powershell で activate する方法

Powershell で Anaconda の仮想環境を切り替えられないのは既知の問題です。[この issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626) に情報が集約されています。

2018年3月現在解決されておらず、以下のワークアラウンドが知られています。

#### 方法1

[pscondaenvs](https://anaconda.org/pscondaenvs/pscondaenvs) を使う。

```
conda install -n root -c pscondaenvs pscondaenvs
```

#### 方法2

Powershell の中で `cmd` を起動し、`activate` してから Powershell に戻る。

### 2. デフォルトの設定を変えるには

> (デフォルトをPython3.6にするには) rootのバージョンを3.6にアップデートにしてから、3.5.2を新しく構築するものなのでしょうか？

はい。仮想環境は一時的な環境変更のために使うものなので、デフォルトを 3.6 にしたいのであればデフォルトの環境においてアップデートすれば良いです。このときに今のデフォルト環境を失いたくないのであれば、仮想環境をコピーする (clone する) ことが[できます](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#cloning-an-environment)。

Anaconda の仮想環境についての詳細は、[公式ドキュメント](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)をご参照下さい。

### 3. Anaconda の「環境」と virtualenv の違い

大雑把な説明ですが、conda コマンドは virtualenv コマンドと pip コマンドを統合したものです。Anaconda 公式ドキュメントの[こちら](https://conda.io/docs/commands.html#conda-vs-pip-vs-virtualenv-commands)に比較があるのですが、virtualenv 単体では仮想環境の中でパッケージをインストールすることができません (pip を使います)。また、そもそも Anaconda Cloud のパッケージを使うには conda コマンドを使うことになります。

Python の仮想環境ツールは他に pyenv というのもあります。本家 Stack Overflow に三者を比較する投稿がいくつかあるので、ご覧ください。

- [What is the difference between pyenv, virtualenv, anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38217545/5989200)
- [Does Conda replace the need for virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34398676/5989200)
- [What is the relationship between virtualenv and pyenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29950300/5989200)